# Rails & Jquery: Filter Cities According To Selected State Option

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can't figure out how to filter cities based on the selected state's ID using the JQuery filter() method and rails. Already watched Railscasts #88 regular and revised, but I'm not using optgroup, so his recommended way of doing it isn't working. What I'm looking for is what to put inside the filter() method call below. I suspect it should be something like:

```
.filter("select label='job_state_id' "))
```

Anyway, here is the JQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  
     // grab all cities for later filtering
     cities = $('#job_city_id').html();
    $('#job_state_id').change(function(){
      state = $('#job_state_id option:selected').text();
      // can't figure out how to only display cities of the selected state, hence filter() is blank below
      options = $(cities).filter().text();
      $('#job_city_id').html(options);
  });
 });
```

The Rails model

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :city

class State < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :citys
  has_many :jobs

class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :state
  has_many :jobs
```

The Rails form

```
<div class="field" >
        <%= f.label :state_id %>
        <%= f.collection_select :state_id, State.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => '-- Select a US State --'} %>
</div>
    <div class="field"> 
    <%= f.label :city_id %>
    <%= f.collection_select :city_id, City.all, :id, :name, {:prompt => '-- Select a US City --'} %>
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="field" >
        <label for="job_state_id">State</label>
        <select name="job[state_id]" id="job_state_id"><option value="">-- Select a US State --</option>
<option value="1">California</option>
<option value="2">Nevada</option>
<option value="3">Oregon</option>
<option value="4">Alaska</option></select>
</div>
    <div class="field"> 
    <label for="job_city_id">City</label>
    <select name="job[city_id]" id="job_city_id"><option value="">-- Select a US City --</option>
<option value="1">Los Angeles</option>
<option value="2">San Francisco</option>
<option value="3">Portland</option></select>
</div>
```

Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have enough information in the view as it currently is to be able to do what you want... there's nothing in the view that can be used to deduce that "Los Angeles" is in "California".

You could do this with an ajax call... when `#job_state_id` changes send a request to the rails app and the rails app will return a new options list.

Alternatively you could create a hidden div with multiple internal divs, containing all city options grouped (per div) by state id, then copy the html of the div relating to the selected state...

```
<div style=style="display: none;">
  <% current_state_id = nil %>
  <% City.order_by(:state_id).each do |city| %>
    <% if city.state_id != current_state_id %>
      <% if current_state_id %>
        </div>
      <% end %>
      <% current_state_id = city.state_id %>
      <div id='<%=current_state_id %>'>
    < % end %>
    <option value="<%= city.id %>"><%=city.name%></option>
  <% end %>
  <% if current_state_id %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Then in your code when the state changes do...

```
var state = $('#job_state_id option:selected').val();
$('#job_city_id').html($('#' + state).html());
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback and ideas Steve - it sounds like there are many ways to accomplish this!  -Dan